# How can i merge only the change set, rather than the whole branch in GIT?

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, branching-and-merging, changeset

I have worked on a ticket generated at JIRA, now I want to merge only the changes that are regarding that change and don't want to merge other changes using Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge a single commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664801/how-do-i-merge-a-single-commit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+merge+single+commit